# How many mega pixel camera is required for Road sign Detection and Front car distance Estimation?

Tags: image-processing, camera

How much resolution camera is required for road sign detection and distance Estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a complex question with no simple answer.

It depends on the situation, aks yourself:

- How accurate does it need to be?
- At what distance shall it detect?
- Are there time constraints? (More processing time needed for large images)

More information isn't always better for object detection. My suggestion is to experiment and start with the simple and cheap alternatives.